# Asset Pipline, how to add image path to background: url()?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to add image_path to compiled css?

I have to add image **author.png**, and i put it to **application.css**:

```
.post-author-icon {

    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url("../design/users/author.png")
        no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:2px;
}
```

then i run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` end get files in `public/assets`

```
assets/application-e1664a39d94f9050096cb42d545f13c8.css
```

and

```
assets/design/users/author-d5ad9ee413cd0b00e2a0d226eac97cc2.png
```

of course browser don't load the image because in CSS image stil have same name.

How to fix this problem?

This is Ruby on Rails v4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take advantage of the asset pipeline's ability to process ERB or SASS. I like SASS, so I'll provide an example for that.

1. Rename `application.css` to `application.css.scss`
2. Change the `background` style to

   ```
   background: image-url("design/users/author.png");
   ```

You can find more information on this helper and others in the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)**.

Comment: I like ERB, and for that, you need to swap the file extension from scss to erb, and swap image-url for image_url wrapped in erb <%= %> brackets